# RestKit Serialization of related entities

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to send a POST request with RestKit. I have an entity (called `workout`) that I want to serialize and send to my server backend.

The `workout` Entity `has-one` related Entity (called `exercise`) which has a `name`.

The Problem I have is that my server expects the JSON in a little bit different format than what RestKit sends:

What the backend receives is the following: `exercise[name]`. Note that the `name` attribute of the related entity `exercise` is in square brackets.

My Server expects these attributes in the following form: `exercise.name`.

My question is: How can I tell RestKit to use a dot instead of square brackets when serializing entities?

I've looked into `setSourceToDestinationKeyTransformationBlock` but I could'nt figure out how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: Show what the server expects (full format) and your mappings and descriptors code.

Comment: Also, what version of RestKit and have you set the serialisation type?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I've added the serialisation type like this: objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; and it did the trick! Thank you. If you post an answer I will make it the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default RestKit will use form URL encoded serialisation (and that's what it looks like you're getting). To correct this, set the serialisation type to JSON:

```
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```